# add ThreadPoolTaskExecutor to existing applicaiton context programatically

Tags: spring, threadpoolexecutor, applicationcontext

I am using existing applicationContext.xml that is being used for our existing web application to create a new console based java process.

This process or accounting server is to process tasks of different companies (lets say 2 different companies at a time). For this [ThreadPoolTaskExecutor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html) gives a guarantee that no more than the defined limit threads will be executed.

In below snippet when I try to get the "taskExecutor" from application context it is throwing exception that no such bean exists

is it the correct way to register a component ? as am not getting the thread pool bean from application context, is it properly registered with application context ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOGGER.info("Starting Accounting Server ...");
        
        LOGGER.info("initializing applicationContext ... from " + APPLICATION_CONTEXT_XML_FULL_PATH);

        try (AbstractApplicationContext applicationContext = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("file:" + APPLICATION_CONTEXT_XML_FULL_PATH)) {
            LOGGER.info("... applicationContext initialized");

            
            ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPool = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
            threadPool.setCorePoolSize(MAX_RUNNING_THREADS);
            threadPool.setMaxPoolSize(MAX_RUNNING_THREADS);
            threadPool.setThreadNamePrefix("T--ACCOUNTING-THREAD--");
            threadPool.initialize();
            
            Object obj = applicationContext.getBeanFactory().initializeBean(threadPool, "taskExecutor");
            // obj is returned
            
            obj = applicationContext.getBean("taskExecutor"); // <--------- throws exception with no such bean
            
            AccountingQueueTransacitonService accountingQueueTransacitonService = applicationContext.getBean(AccountingQueueTransacitonService.class);
            
            /*
            while (hastasks) {
                // TODO:
                // get tasks
                // add to thread and push to thread pool
                // get some sleep
                // update hastasks flag
            }
            */
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e, e);
        } finally {
            LOGGER.info("closed application context ...");
        }
        
        LOGGER.info("Ending Accounting Server gracefully ...");
    }
```

Comment: No it is not. Why not simply define in the XML file?

Comment: same is used in web application and is load balanced on multiple servers

Comment: That still doesn't answer the question. What prevents you from adding that threadpool as configuraiton to the xml?

Comment: 1- this should not be the part of web application
2- same web application is deployed on multiple servers, but this should be only single process

Comment: Add an additinal XML with the threadpool and load that next to the basic XML. Or write a dedicated XML file and don't reuse the existing configuration (as that will include much stuff you won't need like all the stuff related to the web).

Comment: ok, but what is causing to throw the exception when i am trying to get the bean by "taskExecutor" name ?

Comment: Because that isn't the way to register a bean, nor does it add anything to add it to the context.

Comment: please advise the correct way

Comment: Have you actually read my comments? Create an additional XML file to create the task executor, load both.

Comment: already did that by registering a custom ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean, but still looking for a better solution as it's a legacy webapp

Comment: Why would you need a custom factorybean? You are making it way to complicated... You only need to load an additional XML, anything else is the wrong solution.